# Posting to Facebook - Graph API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have managed to successfully read my Facebook account by using the following code:

```
IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            if (authorization == null)
            {
                // Kick off authorization request
                client.RequestUserAuthorization();
            }
            else
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
                Session["access_token"] = authorization.AccessToken;
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                        this.nameLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(graph.Name);
                    }


                }
            }
```

I am now trying to POST to my Facebook news feed and I am struggling to find a guide to help me through it. I have tried to start it myself and for some reason it seems to throw back a 400: Bad Request error.

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?");

        var postdata = "message=hello";
        postdata += "&access_token" + Session["access_token"].ToString();
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Can anyone help me understand why my code is returning the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://facebooksdk.net/ to make your job simple. Store access token and reuse for every request till it gets expired.